# Ajax submit multipart form without defining form fields

Tags: jquery, forms

I want to submit a form through ajax that contains a file input. This would use an XMLHttpRequest or an iframe fallback. Preferably, I would use a plugin to achieve this, however, as far as I can see pretty much all plugins don't use existing forms but create their own, and require additional fields to be handset. My form is created by a framework and it already works, including CSRF-protection for example. So I don't want to change the backend, nor do I want to hardcode the fields and the form properties in the plugin, I just want to tell it 'here's the form, just handle it. And if the form will change (which it very likely will in the near future) I want the submit to work without changing anything.

Are there ways to get existing plugins such as Dropzone, Jquery File Upload (or just the Iframe Transport part of it) to use existing forms as a basis? Or is there another plugin that does exactly this?

Answer (score -1):

Dropzone works with existing forms.

```
<form action="/upload" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="xxx" />
</form>
```

Dropzone will automatically find the form(with class `dropzone`) and initialize a new dropzone.

From the doc:

> That's it. Dropzone will find all form elements with the class
>   dropzone, automatically attach itself to it, and upload files dropped
>   into it to the specified action attribute.

Here is an example I wrote recently:

https://github.com/wong2/doora/blob/master/templates/index.html#L66

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't use existing file input fields - you need to configure it with the paramName option, and hide the default file input. Perhaps that is still the way to go, but...

Comment: why would you have to use the existing file input?

Comment: Because it already exists and is generated and validated by the framework.